# CSS steps animation shaking image

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to do a simple animation but the result isn't smooth.

```css
.animate {
    animation: infinity 1.5s steps(27) forwards;
}

@keyframes infinity {
    100% {
        background-position: -5778px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="animate" style="width:214px; height:32px; background-image:url(https://i.hizliresim.com/gOggGZ.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

So is there any way to remove that shaking?

Comment: Why using `animation-timing-function` as `steps(3)` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can't see the snippet, please fix it so we can help better.

On a side note, if the animation is not smooth, maybe transition will help. You can't give the number of steps as 'steps(3)', there is a CSS property

> animation-iteration-count: 3;

which determines how many times it should be repeated after completing one full loop. You can use 'infinite' too.

Also, you should maybe also define the 0% for better control over the element animation you want.

```css
.animate {
    animation: infinity 1.5s linear forwards; /*add transition here */
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

/* or on the element itself */
.elementclassname {
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

@keyframes infinity {
    0% {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: -300px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `animation-timing-function` to `ease-in-out` gives smooth animation.

```css
.animate {
  animation: infinity 1.5s ease-in-out forwards;
 }
 @keyframes infinity {
  0% {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
  100% {
 background-position: -300px;
 }
 }
```

```html
<div class="animate" style="width:200px; height:100px; background-image:url(https://preview.ibb.co/k2cREc/banner_about.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;    -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);-o-transform: rotate(-8deg);-ms-transform: rotate(-8deg); transform: rotate(-8deg);"></div>
```

Comment: Ok. i got it but if i use drawing animation. Letters appaers every step.

Comment: There is nothing in your snippet , can u edit that ,it will be helpful to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly asking CSS to make an animation with 3 steps, this is why your animation isn't smooth.

Simply remove the `steps(3)` part and you'll be good!

```css
.animate {
  animation: infinity 1.5s forwards;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/M5XHVHu.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}

@keyframes infinity {
  100% {
    background-position: -300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animate"></div>
```